# Perform signed arithmetic on numbers defined as bit ranges of unsigned bytes

Tags: c#

I have two bytes.  I need to turn them into two integers where the first 12 bits make one int and the last 4 make the other.  I figure i can && the 2nd byte with 0x0f to get the 4 bits, but I'm not sure how to make that into a byte with the correct sign.

update:
just to clarify I have 2 bytes

```
byte1 = 0xab
byte2 = 0xcd
```

and I need to do something like this with it

```
var value = 0xabc * 10 ^ 0xd;
```

sorry for the confusion.

thanks for all of the help.

Comment: First as in MSB and last as in LSB?

Comment: The question title doesn't seem to match the question itself ("turn into signed byte" -- "turn into two integers"). What exactly do you need?

Comment: I agree with dtb. It's not really clear what output you want, or how you expect the signing to work with a "byte with the correct sign". If you only have four bits forming that byte, is the most significant of the four bits then your sign bit?

Comment: @Kongress - yes the the most significant bit of the four bits would be the sign bit.

Comment: @dtb - I need an int but I figured if I could get the signed byte correctly I could convert that to an int.

Comment: @dtb, Kongress - I've updated the question. If you feel the question should be reworded feel free to edit it or let me know and I'll change it.

Comment: So stealing dtb's template, if your two bytes are `0xab` and `0xcd`, you want a signed `int 0xabc` and a signed `sbyte 0xd`, yes?

Comment: @kongress - yes exactly. which none of the current answers do.

Comment: So you have an `sbyte` rather than a `byte`. That makes a big difference.

Comment: @scott Ok, redid my answer based on the clarification. See if that works for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, let's try this again knowing what we're shooting for. I tried the following out in VS2008 and it seems to work fine, that is, both `outOne` and `outTwo = -1` at the end. Is that what you're looking for?

```
byte b1 = 0xff;
byte b2 = 0xff;
ushort total = (ushort)((b1 << 8) + b2);
short outOne = (short)((short)(total & 0xFFF0) >> 4);
sbyte outTwo = (sbyte)((sbyte)((total & 0xF) << 4) >> 4);
```

Comment: I understand what this one is doing!

Comment: Nah, I had to do some casting for your original code anyway :D

Answer (score 4):

```
int a = 10;
int a1 = a&0x000F;
int a2 = a&0xFFF0;
```

try to use this code

Answer (score 4):

For kicks:

```
public static partial class Levitate
{
    public static Tuple<int, int> UnPack(this int value)
    {
        uint sign = (uint)value & 0x80000000;
        int small = ((int)sign >> 28) | (value & 0x0F);
        int big = value & 0xFFF0;

        return new Tuple<int, int>(small, big);
    }
}

int a = 10;
a.UnPack();
```

Comment: doing it this way will cause small to always be positive right?

Comment: @scott - Yea, I missed the signed discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the following to bytes:

```
byte a = 0xab;
byte b = 0xcd;
```

and consider 0xab the first 8 bits and 0xcd the second 8 bits, or 0xabc the first 12 bits and 0xd the last four bits. Then you can get the these bits as follows;

```
int x = (a << 4) | (b >> 4);   // x == 0x0abc
int y = b & 0x0f;              // y == 0x000d
```

Answer (score 0):

edited to take into account clarification of "signing" rules:

```
public void unpack( byte[] octets , out int hiNibbles , out int loNibble )
{
  if ( octets        == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException("octets");
  if ( octets.Length != 2    ) throw new ArgumentException("octets") ;

  int value = (int) BitConverter.ToInt16( octets , 0 ) ;

  // since the value is signed, right shifts sign-extend
  hiNibbles =   value >>  4         ;
  loNibble  = ( value << 28 ) >> 28 ;

  return ;
}
```

Comment: this doesn't keep the sign from C for the loNibble or the sign from F for the high nibbles

Comment: Not from my reading of what the OP wants: the 3 hi-order nibbles represent a signed int and the 1 lo-order nibble forms a signed int, each with its own sign. The lo nibble gets the appropriate sign because of we shift that bit into the sign position (and then shift it right back out).